# Add key and value array to array multidimensional

Tags: arrays, multidimensional-array, key-value

I want to add key and value form array multidimensional to other array multidimensional. I have 2 array multidimensional, this is:

```
$data1 = array(
   array('id' => 1, 'name' => 'Dani'),
   array('id' => 2, 'name' => 'Maachan'),
);

$data2 = array(
   array('id' => 2, 'class' => 'Informatics'),
);
```

I want to join that's 2 array multidimensional to a array multidimensional with "id" in $data1 has some value "id" in $data2 like this:

```
$dataResult = array(
   array('id' => 1, 'name' => 'Dani', 'class' => ''),
   array('id' => 2, 'name' => 'Maachan', 'class => 'Informatics'),
);
```

I hope you can help me, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

This works

```
$data1 = array(
   array('id' => 1, 'name' => 'Dani'),
   array('id' => 2, 'name' => 'Maachan'),
);

$data2 = array(
   array('id' => 2, 'class' => 'Informatics'),
);

//first lets sort out data2
$new_data2 = array();
foreach($data2 as $d){
    $new_data2[$d['id']] = $d['class'];
}

$new_data1 = array();
//now lets create a final array
foreach($data1 as $d){
    $d['class'] = array_key_exists($d['id'], $new_data2) ? $new_data2[$d['id']] : '' ;;
    $new_data1[] = $d;
}

echo '<pre>';
print_r($new_data1);
echo '</pre>';
```